# How to exit from a Scrapy Python script after spiders stopped crawling or encountered exception?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to run my Scrapy's python script from a bat file within a Window's Task Scheduler every minute.

However the python script somehow did not exit and it is blocking all future task startup from the Task Scheduler.

So, my questions here are,

1. How can I exit my Scrapy script elegantly after the spiders have completed running?
2. How can I exit the Scrapy script when encountering Exception, especially ReactorNotRunning Error?

Thank you All in advance.

This is my bat file to run the python script

```
@echo off
python "C:\Scripts\start.py"
pause
```

This is my python script

```
from cineplex.spiders import seatings_spider as seat
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
import sys
import time
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer


def crawl_all_showtimes():
    # Create a CrawlerRunner instance to manage multiple spider simultaneously
    runner = CrawlerRunner()

    # Check folder for today
    directory_for_today = utils.create_dir_for_today(PARENT_DIR)

    # Get all cinema id and names first
    cinema_dict = utils.get_all_cinemas()

    # Prepare for crawling
    crawl_showtimes_helper(directory_for_today, cinema_dict, runner)

    # Start Crawling for Showtimes
    reactor.run()


# Helps to run multiple ShowTimesSpiders sequentially
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl_showtimes_helper(output_dir, cinema_dict, runner):
    # Iterate through all cinema to get show timings
    for cinema_id, cinema_name in cinema_dict.iteritems():
        yield runner.crawl(st.ShowTimesSpider, cinema_id=cinema_id,     cinema_name=cinema_name, output_dir=output_dir )
    reactor.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Turns on Scrapy Logging
    configure_logging()

    # Collect all Seatings
    crawl_all_seatings()
```

Answer (score -1):

The main thread of the program blocks for some Scrapy threads. So in your main program use this:

```
import sys;
sys.exit()
```